# i dont know where im wrong in this python code of conditional statements using if elif and else

Tags: python, conditional-statements

[this is what I'm trying to do but it keeps on saying something is wrong in line 15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kK4XJ.png)

Comment: please paste your code and don't use an img

Comment: can you copy paste it into your post? the page is blocked by the internet i'm using right now sorry

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and make sure to **ask a question**. Before posting to Stack Overflow, you should try to [understand](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and [locate](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the problem yourself, and try to create a [mre]; then show the relevant code [as text, not an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551), using [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), along with a [complete error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146).

Comment: "but it keeps on saying something is wrong in line 15" I can guarantee that "it" doesn't *just* "say something is wrong"; it *tells you* what it thinks is wrong. You should start by trying to *read* and *understand* that message. If you will not read what the IDE has to tell you, why should we trust that you will read any answer we try to give you?

Comment: It says indentation error but im just learning i checked and i feel everything i did is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in your code because you can not have an `elif` statement after an `else` statment.

Your code

```py
if #something:
   #something
else #something:
   #something
elif #something:
   #something
```

Correct way:

```py
if #something:
   #something
elif #something:
   #something
else #something:
   #something
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is nexted if and else should be intended
other wise the first else goes with first else

```
avarage_grade =7
attendance=1
if (avarage_grade>=6):
    if(attendance>=0.8):
        print('student has passed')
    else: #here
        print("student has failed due to low attendance rate") # and here
elif(attendance>0.8):
    print("student has failed due to low avarage_grade")
else:
    print("student has failed due to low avarage_grade and low attendance rate")
```

also please post your code also... for future anyone to see